# Function Doesn't return

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct m_queue{
       int ndata;
       struct m_queue* pnext;
       struct m_queue* pdown;
       };

 int search(struct m_queue* list,int key){  //returns the index where it founded the key, return -1 if key is not found
        struct m_queue* temp;//searches horizontal
        struct m_queue* run;//searches downward
        int i;
        temp = list;

        run = temp->pdown;

        getch();
        while(temp!=NULL){

            getch();
            while(run!=NULL){
                if(run->ndata == key)
                    return temp->ndata;
                else
                    run = run->pdown;
            }
            temp = temp->pnext;
            run = temp->pdown;

        }
        printf("returning -1");
        getch();
        return -1;

    }
```

i checked the other functions already and i'm pretty sure there's no flaw but whenever i debug my program it always highlight the segment "run = temp->pdown". this functions doesn't return -1 it just return if it found the key. this was coded in c language

Comment: Do you set pnext to null when creating a new element?

Comment: ... same for `pdown`.

Answer (score 1):

If `temp` is `NULL`, `run = temp->pdown;` is an invalid operation.

```
}
temp = temp->pnext;
if (temp!=NULL)  //add this line
    run = temp->pdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in these lines:

```
      temp = temp->pnext;
      run = temp->pdown;
```

what happens when `temp` is NULL? You are trying to access `temp->pdown` without checking whether `temp` is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //run = temp->pdown;                    //this statement not needed

    getch();
    while(temp!=NULL){
        run = temp->pdown;                 //add this statement
        getch();
        while(run!=NULL){
            if(run->ndata == key) 
               return temp->ndata;
            else
                run = run->pdown;
        }
        temp = temp->pnext;
       // run = temp->pdown;              // this statement not needed
  }
```

make this change to avoid accessing temp when it is NULL.